# nanogallery2: Is it possible to go to a link instead of opening lightbox when a thumbnail is clicked

Tags: javascript, gallery, nanogallery

I am using [nanogallery2][1]. I add some items dynamically to my gallery (by using this sample: https://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/wJKowg). I know that by setting the option `thumbnailOpenImage: false` we can disable showing lightbox when a thumbnail is clicked. Is it possible to set a link for items in the gallery to send the user to that link when he touches the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom URL with the property `destinationURL`.

From the mentioned Codepen, here's an example:

```
  ...
  // create the new item
  var ID = ngy2data.items.length + 1;
  var albumID = '0';
  var newItem = NGY2Item.New(instance, 'new berlin ' + ID, '', ID, albumID, 'image', '' );

  // define thumbnail -> image displayed in the gallery
  newItem.thumbSet( baseURL + 'berlin2t.jpg', 135, 204); // w,h

  // define URL of the media to display in lightbox
  newItem.setMediaURL( baseURL + 'berlin2.jpg', 'img');

  // DEFINE YOUR SPECIFIC URL
  newItem.destinationURL = "[CUSTOM_URL]";

  ...
```

No need to disable the `thumbnailOpenImage` option.

#### Alternative solution:

Use the `fnThumbnailOpen` callback.

Here's an example that shows how to replace the internal lightbox with Fancybox: https://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/zZNMJj